# remove spacing from css <em> tag

Tags: jquery, css, spacing

I'm using the em tag on a web app to high light when a certain event happens and incasing the text in `<em></em>` and using css to highlight the background green and display as a block so it creates a green section of text; however, `<em></em>` is adding space in between my lines, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.  `line-height` doesn't seem to work, and the spacing is fine without the `<em></em>` brackets.

**Solution**

You're right, I should have included the code.  I thought it would be an easy answer and after looking it over in the Element section of Development Tools, I didn't see any margins or padding that would cause it.  I've figured out that it is because in my non  code, I put a  after each line, but when I incase the part I want in the  code, it effectively adds its own break at the end to go to the next line, so the extra spacing was because I left in , once removed, it worked fine.  I'll post my code below for reference.

Original code:

```
$('#Waiting_Name').html($('#Waiting_Name').html() + "<em>" + data[i].Patient_Name + "</em></br>");
```

New code:

```
$('#Waiting_Name').html($('#Waiting_Name').html() + "<em>" + data[i].Patient_Name + "</em>");
```

Comment: Please include your HTML / CSS

Comment: Can you show us your code? Or maybe include a Fiddle?

Comment: As always with such questions: open your browsers development console and _look_ what is causing the space. Right click on the element, chose "Inspect element" and investigate the css rules applied to the element. You can even play around with them right there in the console in a live manner.

Comment: I can only guess without seeing your code that you have a different font size set for your <em> tags than you do for the rest of your body paragraph font. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpBGqe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the em tag on a web app to high light when a certain event happens and incasing the text in `<em></em>` and using css to highlight the background green and display as a block so it creates a green section of text; however, `<em></em>` is adding space in between my lines, and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.  `line-height` doesn't seem to work, and the spacing is fine without the `<em></em>` brackets.

**Solution**

You're right, I should have included the code.  I thought it would be an easy answer and after looking it over in the Element section of Development Tools, I didn't see any margins or padding that would cause it.  I've figured out that it is because in my non  code, I put a  after each line, but when I incase the part I want in the  code, it effectively adds its own break at the end to go to the next line, so the extra spacing was because I left in , once removed, it worked fine.  I'll post my code below for reference.

Original code:

```
$('#Waiting_Name').html($('#Waiting_Name').html() + "<em>" + data[i].Patient_Name + "</em></br>");
```

New code:

```
$('#Waiting_Name').html($('#Waiting_Name').html() + "<em>" + data[i].Patient_Name + "</em>");
```